# How to make a data frame from a text file in R

Tags: r

I have a text file (Assignment_02_Data) that looks like that:

| Gene | Sample1 | Sample2 | Sample3 | Sample4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gene1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| Gene2 | 4 | 6 | 9 | 3 |
| Gene3 | 3 | 6 | 2 | 7 |
| Gene4 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 6 |
| Gene5 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 1 |

I am trying to read the gene expression (GE) dataset in the accompanying file titled
“Assignment_02_Data.txt” as a data frame called GE, then compute the mean of GE across samples for each gene.

That's how I try:

```
path.name = "D:/Courses/Bioinformatics Diploma/Statistical Analysis and Visualization/Assignments/Assignment 2/Assignment_02_Data.txt"
GE = read.csv(path.name, sep = '\t')
GE_Mean = apply(GE, 2, mean)
```

I got this error:
Warning messages:

```
1: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
4: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
5: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

can someone tell me what's wrong??

Comment: Your file isn't being read in well. Can you copy paste the top of the file into the question, without all the fancy table formatting? What you show is, e.g., `|Gene  |Sample1|Sample2|Sample3|Sample4|`, then the next line `|------|-------|-------|-------|-------|`, etc. Are you sure your file is actually tab separated?

Comment: Or maybe there are strange values preventing your numeric-looking columns from being imported as numerics...

Comment: Gene Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4
Gene1 1 2 3 4
Gene2 4 6 9 3
Gene3 3 6 2 7
Gene4 2 1 4 6
Gene5 4 2 3 1
this is my file

Comment: Please put that in your question with code formatting -- down here in comments there are no line breaks, no difference between tabs and spaces, ...

Comment: If you have a column with the gene name, you can't take the `mean()` of a gene name. Make sure all of your columns are actually numeric by looking at `str(GE)`

Comment: Can you add `dput(head(GE))` to your post? Have you tried `colMeans(GE[-1])` ?

Comment: @RonakShah it printed the means of columns but not the first one

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).